# How can I add external node to EKS cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am considering to use AWS EKS to deploy kubernete cluster but I wonder whether it supports bring other nodes in the cluster? Other nodes may come from GCP, on-prem infra. etc.

Comment: What do you think about creating two k8s clusters: one `EKS` and one e.g `GKE` and managing them using [Anthos](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/multicluster-management) or Rancher ?
In my opinion it will be much easier.